# Code leaving random string at end of output

Tags: python

So i have made the code and it all checks out but when i run it, you would have to create your own text file, i get the random output of (1, '\n'). I cant explain it properly because im quite new so i hope the code helps.

I have got what i expected to happen however at the end of every line that is printed to the user, the annoying (1,'\n') appears as well.

Comment: Can you post the file you are reading

Comment: yes sure. It is a text file by the name of Earth.txt                   inside it is this:    aaaabbdffee
ccrrffddgfdss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file.readline` method always returns a string with a trailing newline character (unless it's at the end of file and the file does not end with a newline character), so you should use the `str.rstrip` method to remove the trailing newline character before processing the string:

```
line1 = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: Careful, as this may also remove any spaces at the end of the line.

Comment: I've updated the code so that it will only remove trailing newline characters then.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.readline()
```

Reads each line in the file, including empty lines, for which it will just return the linebacker ('\n'). Usually you don't see it because print() handles it automatically, but your function counts this as a separate character. See if you have any empty lines at the end of your file, and just backspace them and save. 
Hope this helps.